template instantiation and symbol resolution problem
in c++, the standard library is implemeted in template, which means that they will be instantiated in each shared libraries, there must be that two libs have the same function with the same name, for example std::vector<std::string>, different libraries might both instantiated it, then when those libs are used in one same process, how the linker resolve the symbols, does this means that only one code in one lib is used?
if the linker use the implementation in lib a for example, when program ends and lib a is unmapped, will it cause other libs that use implementation fail?
--edit--
For anyone that might interest in this topic, I summarized relevent topic and write it down at: https://shan-weiqiang.github.io/2024/11/03/symbols-libraries-one-definition-rule.html

Templates are expanded (instantiated) where they are used and do not produce unsatisfied fixups.  In the same module the linker can fold identical code to reduce code-bloat but this is not required.

@wohlstad i want to know how the linker cope with it? is there any docs i can look into?

@shan Start with a Q about a single module with 2 translation units (TUs) using std::vector.  The Q as asked would need an essay.

@RichardCritten, template functions are not necessarily in-lined. If not, then different shared libs often have same symbols exported, my question is how linker handle this situation

@shan I am not aware of documents explaining the implementation details of a linker. But e.g. gcc is open source, I guess you can dig into it if you are interested.

Notice I didn't say exported symbol, but missing fixups.  Multiple exported symbols are not problem if no code is trying to fix up to them.  ( there is redundant duplicate code but linkers / loaders can collapse these ) .

@RichardCritten i think Multiple exported same-named symbols is a problem and i want to know how the dynamic linker solves this problem. Is there any referencing counting for a shared lib to count that it's symbols being used, something like that

Why is it a problem is no code is using these "...same-named symbols .."?   For example using std::vector<int> in a TU does not create any missing/unresolved externals.  So there is no need to resolve any thing.

@RichardCritten lib a instantiate std::vector<int> , lib b also instantiate std::vector<int>, they both exported symbols for std::vector<int>, when these two libs are used in the same program, dynamic linker have to choose which implementation to use for std::vector<int>, lib a or lib b, this makes lib a and lib b inter-dependend, hope that i explained my question this way

It loads them both as there is NOTHING trying to fix up to them.  It can code-fold them how ever this is not required.

@RichardCritten because for global funtion and variables, there must be only one implementation inside one program

Why do you believe that if two libraries instantiate a std::vector<int> they will both export the exact same symbol at the exact same address?

nothing prevents each library from having and using its own version of the function, the answer is very platform and compiler dependent, the compiler doesn't need to use the exported symbol when resolving functions because it can inline or create static versions of functions, for windows as functions are not exported by default each dll will have its version of each function, on linux whether you use your shared object's version of the function or the exported one is up to the compiler, it is not obligated to use the one in the symbols table, there is nothing in the standard to obligate it

@OldBoy it has nothing to do with address, it's about same implementation in different libraries with the same symbol name

as for globals, things like std::any have this problem where it is not guarateed to work across library boundaries because it uses globals, and globals in different libraries don't necessarily need to map to the same variables, also if you statically link the C++ runtime then exceptions won't work across library boundaries and heap deallocations could crash, again because they rely on globals

See inline specifier "...A function defined entirely inside a class/struct/union definition, whether it's a member function or a non-member friend function, is implicitly an inline function..." and "...If an inline function or variable(since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required ...."

@RichardCritten yes, inline function not endure this problem. but template function can also be non-inline functions

Only if you manually instantiate them see Why can templates only be implemented in the header file? for the full details.

@shan That makes no sense, different libraries are totally isolated from each other. And what do you mean by "same symbol name"? I would be interested to see some sample code that you believe would cause any problem.

@OldBoy see my comment starting from line 21: https://github.com/shan-weiqiang/cplusplus/blob/main/ODR/a.cpp, if you can not open it, please let me know

You misunderstand ODR.  Most ways of violating ODR are Undefined Behaviour No Diagnostic Required (NDR).  ODR is a restriction on the programmer not the implementation.

@RichardCritten in my code, i do not violate ODR, ODR only requires that no same definition in one translation unit, it allows multiple definition in different translation unit, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Start with the obvious: libraries are loaded in one order, unloaded in the reverse order, exactly so that non-cyclical dependencies can work.
Now ask the question again: how can the dynamic linker resolve a symbol so that it's not prematurely unloaded? The answer is trivial: just use the first occurrence. It will be unloaded last.
Note that most std::vector<std::string> methods are likely to be inlined and simply won't appear in any library, precisely because they're templates. operator[] for instance is not a whole lot more than a simple addition.

that's very clever and answer my questions.. Just for sure, is this the real implementation of the linker(linux)?

Things are a bit more complicated. I find the following ACCU 2024 great talk by Roger Orr to be very relevant to this discussion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HakSW8wIH8A. Touching shared libs and ODR at 38m39s, templates and ODR on the linker level, at 1h8m18s and referring to templates and ODR with shared libraries at 1h12m47s.
